# Are VS Code Dev Container typically slow when developing with Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, containers

I have a static website built with the Vuejs framework. The website itself is fairly lightweight and I moved it into a VS Code development container so that it can be more conveniently shared / reused by some colleagues.

I noticed however that it takes substantially longer to run `npm install` and `npm run serve`; I suspect it has something to do with directory `node_modules` being sync between the host machine and the container.

Is this to be expected or are there methods to optimize performance?

#### `devcontainer.json`

```
{
    "name": "Personal Website Dev Container",
    "dockerFile": "../Dockerfile",
    "forwardPorts": [8080],
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
    },
}
```

#### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is to be expected ;) you can checkout  the following [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/improve-performance#_use-a-targeted-named-volume) to speed up some things.

Basically,  in case you are not using `docker-compose` this is what you have to do (copied from the Microsoft Website)

> ##### Follow these steps:
>
> 1. Use the `workspaceMount` property in `devcontainer.json` to tell VS Code where to bind your source code. Then use the mounts property (VS Code 1.41+) to mount the `node_modules` sub-folder into a named local volume instead.
>
> ```json
> "mounts": [
>    "source=${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules,type=volume"
> ]
> ```
>
> > **Note:** You may use `${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}`, `${devcontainerId}`, or a hardcoded name in the `source`.
>
> 2. Since this repository runs VS Code as the non-root "node" user, we need to add a postCreateCommand to be sure the user can access the folder.
>
> ```json
> "remoteUser": "node",
> "mounts": [
>   "source=${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}-node_modules,target=${containerWorkspaceFolder}/node_modules,type=volume"
> ],
> "postCreateCommand": "sudo chown node node_modules"
> ```
>
> This second step is not required if you will be running in the container as `root`.
>
> If you've already built the container and connected to it, run **Dev Containers: Rebuild Container** from the Command Palette (F1) to pick up the change. Otherwise run **Dev Containers: Open Folder in Container...** to connect to the container.
>
> Two notes on this approach:
>
> 1. If you delete the `node_modules` folder in the container, it may lose the connection to the volume. Delete the contents of the `node_modules` folder instead when needed (`rm -rf node_modules/* node_modules/.*`).
> 2. You'll find that an empty `node_modules` folder gets created locally with this method. This is because the volume mount point in the container is inside the local filesystem bind mount. This is expected and harmless.